# Gimp - Using an image as the transparency layer of another image

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have two images (For the sake of simplicity, Image1 and Image2). I want to use Image2 as a transparency for Image1.

How can I do that? Assume I've done little more with Gimp than play with some filters.

Thanks.

Comment: Is Image2 a grayscale image? Since transparency uses a 0..255 value for each pixel, it is like a grayscale image in this respect.

Comment: For GIMP newbies like myself, the following provides the requisite background and terminology to understand this thread. Helped me anyway.

Docs.Gimp, Chapter 8. Combining Images: 
https://docs.gimp.org/2.6/en/gimp-image-combining.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

OK, so I assume you have two images: a normal image that you want to add transparency to, and a grayscale image that you want to use as its alpha (transparency) channel, something like these:

[image: Base image without transparency]
[image: Alpha mask for image]
<sup>(Base image based on [this photo by John Fielding](http://www.geograph.org.uk/photo/1292959), used under the [CC-By-SA 2.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/); alpha mask created by me using the GIMP's Sphere Designer tool.)</sup>

There are several ways to do this; let me describe a few of them.

**Method 1:** Open both images in the GIMP.
Select the grayscale image and copy it to the clipboard (*Edit → Copy* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
On the base image, select *Layer → Mask → Add Layer Mask...* (also available by right-clicking the layer in the Layers dialog).  It doesn't matter what you choose as the mask, since we'll be replacing it shortly.

The layer mask you just added should be selected for editing; if not, select it with *Layer → Mask → Edit Layer Mask* (or just click the mask in the Layers dialog).  Paste the grayscale image in (*Edit → Paste* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) and anchor the resulting floating selection into the mask (*Layers → Anchor Layer* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, or click the Anchor icon in the Layers dialog).

Optionally, turn the layer mask into an actual alpha channel using *Layer → Mask → Apply Layer Mask* (but simply exporting the image as PNG will do that for you).

**Method 2:** Open the images as layers (*File → Open as Layers...*) or just paste one as a new layer into the other.  With the grayscale image layer visible, open the Channels dialog, right-click one of the Red/Green/Blue channels (they should all be identical) and select *Channel to Selection*.  Invert the selection with *Select → Invert* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Select the base image layer in the Layers dialog.  Add an alpha channel for it with *Layers → Transparency → Add Alpha Channel* if it doesn't have one already, and then cut the selection away from the layer (*Select → Cut* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

**Method 3:** As method 2, but after *Channel to Selection*, don't invert the selection, but simply use *Layer → Mask → Add Layer Mask...* on the base image layer and choose "Selection" from the dialog.  Then optionally apply the mask as in method 1.

---

In any case, whichever method you used, the result should look like this (actual transparent PNG on left, with checkered background on right):

[image: Merged base image and transparency, actual transparency]
[image: Merged base image and transparency, checkered background]

Comment: Method 1: a key point is to anchor the pasted image - if you haven't got the layers dialogue open it's not obvious that even if you do "paste into" the image doesn't become the layer mask until you tell it to anchor.  That's what led to me searching and coming here.

Answer (score 9):

For "layer mask" basics, have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/).

Common algorithm can be:

1. Create *SomeMaskLayer* with transparency.
2. Right-click on the *SomeMaskLayer* and choose “**Alpha To Selection**” <sup>(*In Dock "Layers"*)</sup>
3. Menu **Select** -> **Save To Channel**.
4. Hide *SomeMaskLayer*. <sup>(*In Dock "Layers"*)</sup>
5. Create *SomeRasterLayer*. (File -> Open As Layers, or paint)
6. Right-click on the top layer and choose “**Add layer mask**”. <sup>(*In Dock "Layers"*)</sup>
7. In dialog window choose **Channel** option, and choose your new Channel in the combo. Click **Add**.

Ok, now you have "live mask".

8. Right-click -> **Apply Layer Mask** to baking mask to pixels. <sup>(*In Dock "Layers"*)</sup>

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials. However - They assume a background in graphics, not programming. In addition, I don't get the side-panels they show when I open Gimp. Third, I already tried opening Image1 as the first layer, Image2 as a second layer and then adding a white layer mask while on the second layer. It didn't work.

Comment: Or at least, it appeared not to work. There's no real change in the image whether I invert the colors or not.

Comment: 1.about panels(Docks in GIMP): try to use Single-Window Mode: menu Windows/Single-Window Mode .... 
2.probably just Docks is hidden: menu Windows/Hide Docks (or press Tab)

Comment: at the new channel, I had to set "fill opacity" to 0. Also I did not "apply layer mask" because I still want to be able to change the image. I just wanted to apply transparency on specific regions on all layers. So I added the mask, with channel option, to each of the layers, and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: FYI, both of the above links are spam now.

Answer (score 1):

@IlmariKaronen answer is correct but assumes a little bit of gimp knowledge, so I am writing a step by step guide here, so it's easier to follow for people with zero gimp knowledge. The guide assumes the alpha channel is to be found as a component of another image. First let's copy the alpha channel to be used later with the following steps:

- Open the image you want to use as an alpha channel (or that it contains the alpha channel you want to use) in gimp;
- From the menu, select "*Color -> Components -> Decompose*";
- From the popup window, select the color model (RGB or RGBA), ensure "*Decompose as layers*" is checked, and "*Foreground as registration color" is unchecked*;
- A new image is opened, from the layers window, delete (right click, "*Delete Layer*") or hide (left click on the first thumbnail button) the unwanted layers;
- From the menu, select "*Edit -> Copy Visible*".

Then paste the copied alpha channel to the desired image with the following steps:

- Open the image you want to add the alpha channel to in gimp;
- In the layers window, select the sole layer, right click "*Add Alpha Channel*";
- In the layers window, select the sole layer, right click "*Add Layer Mask*".
- Initialize the layer mask to "*White (full opacity)*", click "*Add*";
- In the layers window, select the sole layer, right click "*Show Layer Mask*";
- Paste the previously copied channel into the active context (CTRL+V) and anchor it (CTRL+H);
- In the layers window, select the sole layer, right click "*Apply Layer Mask*";
- Save the project or export the image to a format supporting transparencies.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that in my opinion is better in certain situations where you may want to edit both the transparency layer and the image. An example is editing using text as the transparency mask.

- Create a new layer group so it doesn't interfere with layers below it.
- Put the Image as the background and the transparency mask layer as the foreground in the layer group.
- In the layers window, select the transparency mask layer, right-click "Edit Layer Attributes"
- Set the "Mode" to "Exclusion"
- Set the "Composite Mode" to "Intersection"