# Image loses transparency when added to another image

Tags: gimp, transparency, gif

Please keep in mind that I have no idea what I’m doing with image editing.

I have a watermark that I want to add to images, but it loses it’s transparency when I try to stick it on a picture.  I’ve tried the watermark as RGB and as greyscale.  I read through the GIMP discussion site and found an answers that gave three possible methods ([here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8397/gimp-using-an-image-as-the-transparency-layer-of-another-image)), but I still couldn’t get it to work.  (I didn’t understand the “Channels dialog” part of the second and third methods, and for the first method, I couldn't get the floating selection anchored in the mask.)

This can't be a hard thing to do — I feel like there’s something very basic that I’m just missing.

Below are the images that I'm using.

The image that I want to watermark:
[image: The image I want to watermark]

The watermark with transparent background:
[image: Watermark]

Same as above, with transparency pattern added for visibility:
[image: The watermark]

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: It seems that your `sushidragon` overlay image does not actually have a transparent background, but a white shape. Looking at the image in a browser on a non-white background [shows this quite obviously](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q3cNC.png). You need to remove that white shape such that only transparency is left. You can find numerous tutorial on how to remove a white background in GIMP, [this is one example](http://acedar.blogspot.nl/2008/01/gimp-tutorial-removing-white.html).

Comment: The watermark is intended to have that little winged shape.  Here's an example where the watermark is functioning properly: [link](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v161/gaiapiccies/example.png). My problem is that the watermark is too opaque.

Comment: Have you tried using a different blending mode for the watermark layer? Or you could change the opacity of the watermark layer. Other than that I think the transparency of the watermark got lost in some conversion you've done on the watermark. I don't know, maybe someone more knowledgeable has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the original poster pointed out in the comments, this can happen if the image has [indexed colours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color), and transparency is not one of the indexed colour values.

You can easily tell if your image is indexed, as the titlebar of gimp will contain **indexed** somewhere past the filename, Also, if your image is indexed, a marker will appear next to the **Indexed...** menu item in the **Image > Mode** menu.

To convert your image to the RGB colourspace, in the menus, choose **Image > Mode > RGB**.